# How to open mobsf using docker

Tags: docker

```
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com


Start interactive shell

laptop@LAPTOP-MDLBUKKN MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker pull opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf
d51af753c3d3: Pull complete                                                                                             fc878cd0a91c: Pull complete                                                                                             6154df8ff988: Pull complete                                                                                             fee5db0ff82f: Pull complete                                                                                             2147c66bc825: Pull complete                                                                                             0adbcd19651f: Pull complete                                                                                             c941f22acae2: Pull complete                                                                                             2b48d720aadd: Pull complete                                                                                             c88c099643b2: Pull complete                                                                                             00718adcba2f: Pull complete                                                                                             9ec8cb716172: Pull complete                                                                                             98b4a4bffe15: Pull complete                                                                                             3d492495d95b: Pull complete                                                                                             ab0f85fef3b0: Pull complete                                                                                             0df7809d4cce: Pull complete                                                                                             8aa79076efbd: Pull complete                                                                                             Digest: sha256:7be8e3b29f2f3ce92077078ac3b053c3bdb33a627ea07256730e92a0fe20d3cb
Status: Downloaded newer image for opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest
docker.io/opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest

laptop@LAPTOP-MDLBUKKN MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ # Static Analysis Only

laptop@LAPTOP-MDLBUKKN MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker run -it -p 8000:8000 opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest
[2020-05-01 03:06:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-05-01 03:06:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2020-05-01 03:06:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
[2020-05-01 03:06:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

How to open mobsf using docker , I have typed some commands , and any mistakes I have made? I still can't open ,dunno know how to open it ..please tell me the solution of the question , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can run docker instance of mobsf via the prebuilt image using below commands

```
docker pull opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf
docker run -it --rm -p 8000:8000 opensecurity/mobile-security-framework-mobsf:latest
```

For more options for running mobsf docker, please view official documentation [here](https://mobsf.github.io/docs/#/docker)

Answer (score -1):

You have probably found a solution to this, but I will recommend **not using the docker version**. If you need help setting it up local this post describes it:

[How to run Mobile Security Framework (MobSF)](https://infosecwriteups.com/automated-mobile-application-security-testing-5b104d88b26)

By running it through docker you will lose the opportunity to use Dynamic analysis (often referred to as "DAST")